# How to switch two nibs from one UIViewController on specific events?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview

I've created two nibs with different views to manage an user profile page with and without registration.

In first nib, there is a text and a button asking user to register (and it call a modalViewController to handle registration/login).
In the second one, I should present user details (Username, image, etc) only if an user is set (this happens after registration/login procedure).

I would like to change the nib to present on this UIViewController but if I make the check on viewDidLoad, the switch does not work.

I've tried to put the if condition to switch nibs in loadView but I got a black screen on view frame.

Any suggestion ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Single UIViewController named ProfileViewController. 
Create two UIViews as resgisterView and loggedView.

All the controls and logics should be in ProfileViewController. While loading the ProfileViewController use if condition to check the status of user and add the corresponding subview accordingly. Use [self.view addSubView:resgisterView] for this. You can put your if inside the viewdidload.

Just keep a break point and check whether this if is working as expected.

Comment: Hi Adarsh, I used this approach and it's working as expected: by registering an observer to user status to switch views, I add or remove them.

My actual trouble is to avoid a refernce to nil: when the user logs out, all his data are nil and UI elements on his profile should be released before dereferncing the User, I suppose...

Comment: I suppose..? Plz complete your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch the ViewControllers in `viewDidAppear` rather than viewdidload. I think i will work.